# ComboBox.SelectedValue is not Working

Tags: c#, winforms, combobox

I have a WinForms application. I've populated my ComboBox with the following code:

```
cboGridSize.Items.Clear();
for (int i = 2; i <= 12; i++)
    cboGridSize.Items.Add(new KeyValuePair<string,int>(i.ToString(), i));
cboGridSize.SelectedValue = 4;
```

However, the last line has absolutely no effect. The ComboBox appears with no items selected.

So I was doing some debugging and noticed some odd things. The following image is from the watch window after setting `cboGridSize.SelectedIndex` to 0.

[Watch Window http://www.softcircuits.com/Client/debugwin.jpg](http://www.softcircuits.com/Client/debugwin.jpg)

Even though the `SelectedItem` property contains exactly what I would expect, `SelectedValue` is still `null`. Although the documentation for `SelectedValue` is pathetic, I understood it would contain the value of the selected item (`SelectedItem`). Instead, the two properties seem completely unrelated. Can anyone see what I have wrong?

As you can see, I have the `ValueMember` property set. And the `DropDownStyle` property is set to `DropDownList`.

---

**EDIT:**

Once Nikolay Khil set me straight on the issue here (why the docs for `SelectedValue` don't do that escapes me), I decided to simply write my own code to accomplish the same task. I'm posting it here in case anyone is interested.

```
static class ComboBoxHelper
{
    public static void LookupAndSetValue(this ComboBox combobox, object value)
    {
        if (combobox.Items.Count > 0)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < combobox.Items.Count; i++)
            {
                object item = combobox.Items[i];
                object thisValue = item.GetType().GetProperty(combobox.ValueMember).GetValue(item);
                if (thisValue != null && thisValue.Equals(value))
                {
                    combobox.SelectedIndex = i;
                    return;
                }
            }
            // Select first item if requested item was not found
            combobox.SelectedIndex = 0;
        }
    }
}
```

This is implemented as an extension method so I simply change my original code as follows:

```
cboGridSize.Items.Clear();
for (int i = 2; i <= 12; i++)
    cboGridSize.Items.Add(new KeyValuePair<string,int>(i.ToString(), i));
cboGridSize.LookupAndSetValue(4);
```

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Both [`ValueMember`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listcontrol.valuemember.aspx) and [`DisplayMember`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listcontrol.displaymember.aspx) properties are used only if [`DataSource`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listcontrol.datasource.aspx) property is defined.

So, you should re-write your code as follows:

```
private readonly BindingList<KeyValuePair<string, int>> m_items =
    new BindingList<KeyValuePair<string, int>>();

public YourForm()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    cboGridSize.DisplayMember = "Key";
    cboGridSize.ValueMember = "Value";
    cboGridSize.DataSource = m_items;

    for (int i = 2; i <= 12; i++)
        m_items.Add(new KeyValuePair<string,int>(i.ToString(), i));

    cboGridSize.SelectedValue = 4;
}
```

Links:

- [BindingList class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132679.aspx)
- [ObservableCollection class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms668604%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)
- [INotifyCollectionChanged Interface](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.specialized.inotifycollectionchanged.aspx)

Comment: Thanks for supplying the missing piece. Knowing this, I may not take the approach you suggest. I may just do a simple lookup on my own. But I knew I was missing some element of this and glad it was finally supplied.

Comment: I noticed that setting SelectedValue only works if the DataSource property is set. If you use comboBox.Items.Add to add items such as a KeyValuePair, setting SelectedValue doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

This does not answer the OP however...the ComboBox SelectedValue must be an integer type.

If you have a short or byte var that holds the value that will set the SelectedValue, it won't work - you will have null/nothing value.

Use an integer.

Comment: This save my day sir. I'm php guy so I'm so use of putting value without specifying its type. The fix is declare a cmbVal as integer = dbReader("local_fk") and it works. Combobox.selectedvalue = cmbVal

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question but I've just come across this problem myself. I solved with the following - it's slightly hacky but it works:

```
        if(newVal != null)
        {
            MyComboBox.SelectedValue = newVal;
        }
        else
        {
            MyComboBox.SelectedIndex = 0; // the 'None Selected' item
        }
```

Hope this helps someone.

Answer (score -2):

u can set SelectedValue first, and then set Datasource and others

Comment: I tried that and it did not work for me. Can you post an example?